Azure Devops Pipeline - how to fetch all files changed on branch without using git commands
I want to run some pytest tests on the files changed in my branch, on which the build pipeline containing all the steps is running. I have this
            displayName: 'Get changed files in the latest commit'
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r $(Build.SourceVersion)^ $(Build.SourceVersion) > changed_files.txt
                cat changed_files.txt

But this does not work - I get fatal: ambiguous argument 'c971d4f8f356595b603d87c3055055fb43ca2752^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. I have tried all the solutions posted on Stackoverflow - checkout with zero depth, fetch using PAT added to url, nothing works. I just need a list of all the files that have been modified in this branch, not just in the latest commit but all of them.

I am willing to bet you are working on a shallow clone.

Another possibility is that that commit is a root commit and so it has no parent.

I dont have an explicit checkout step in my pipeline, it's run by default when the pipeline is triggered. I did add an explicit checkout step with depth=0 but it did not work.

this is the error I get after using checkout step:
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

The last part of the title question (without using git commands) is misleading, it was just based on your early assumption. Maybe remove it to make the question clearer?

To fetch a list of all files changed in a branch in Azure DevOps without using git commands, you can use the Azure DevOps REST API.
The git/commits API allows you to list the commits in a branch, and then you can fetch the changes (files) associated with each commit.
Refer to this link for using the REST API in Azure DevOps Git.
Below code is to fetch a list of all files changed in a branch in Azure DevOps:
import requests
import base64
org_url = "https://dev.azure.com/ORG_Name"
project_name = "Project_Name"
repo_name = "Repo_Name"
pat = "YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"
query_string = "api-version=7.1-preview.1"

token = base64.b64encode(f":{pat}".encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
headers = {'Authorization': f"Basic {token}"}

def fetch_commits(branch_name):
    commits_url = f"{org_url}/{project_name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo_name}/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version={branch_name}&{query_string}"
    response = requests.get(commits_url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        commits = response.json()
        print(f"Commits on branch {branch_name}:")
        for commit in commits['value']:
            print(f"Commit ID: {commit['commitId']} - {commit['comment']}")
       fetch_changes(commit['commitId'])
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch commits: {response.text}")

def fetch_changes(commit_id):
    changes_url = f"{org_url}/{project_name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo_name}/commits/{commit_id}/changes?{query_string}"
    response = requests.get(changes_url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        changes = response.json()
        if 'value' in changes:  # Check if 'value' key exists
            print(f"Files changed in commit {commit_id}:")
            for change in changes['value']:
                print(f"File: {change['item']['path']}")
        else:
            print(f"No changes found in commit {commit_id}.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch changes for commit {commit_id}: {response.text}")

branch_name = "main"  
fetch_commits(branch_name)



